# Select Count Rows Where DATETIME = DATE

Tags: mysql, count

This query converts DATETIME into DATE and return number of rows for same DATE.

```
select*, DATE(call_end) AS Date,
COUNT(*) AS num_emails
from mk_calls mkc 
where call_end >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY
GROUP BY DATE(call_end)
ORDER BY call_start
```

I would like to know how to perform a similar query when the date is known? Is this feasible?

```
$today_date = '2019-06-09';
//perform count query here
```

Comment: What does `$today_date` represent? Is it supposed to replace `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY` altogether?

Comment: Just alter your where clause to use the date comparison, ie. ```WHERE DATE(call_end) = '2019-06-09'```

Comment: @SloanThrasher : Are you sure this would work since call_end is `DATETIME`?

Comment: It should. Easy to type into phpAdmin or similar and test to see. The DATE function should return just the date portion of the DATETIME.

Comment: @SloanThrasher: Yes I'm asking because I already know the answer; I already tried this query `;-)`

Comment: And the answer is???

Comment: @SloanThrasher: It returns 0 row, so it does not work.

Comment: Ok, then explain your expectations. What results would you like this query to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily with MySQLi prepared statements.

```
$sql = 'SELECT *, DATE(call_end) AS Date, COUNT(*) AS num_emails
    FROM mk_calls mkc 
    WHERE call_end >= ?
    GROUP BY DATE(call_end)
    ORDER BY call_start';

$today_date = '2019-06-09';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $today_date);
$stmt->execute();
```

It is generally a bad idea to use `SELECT *`, specially if you use `GROUP BY`